# Stepped down as mod on one site, lost chat room permissions on another?

Tags: support, chat, moderation

I've been a moderator on the Stack Exchange sites *[Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour)* and [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/tour) for years.

This week I stepped down on *Expatriates*, but I have now had my access removed from the [chat with other *Travel* moderators](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54954/mods-are-here). Why? I still appear to have moderator level access to the rest of the travel site.

Others have tried adding me as a room owner, but all that's done is give me read access, which seems weird too.

Any thoughts / fixes appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your diamond on chat was removed because your chat parent was set to the site where you stepped down and no longer had one. Changing the parent to your Travel profile fixes this for you and gives you back a diamond in chat. Any moderator should be able to do this for you and manually refresh your profile, assuming they know to do so.

Comment: looks like someone's set it back to travel now, so all good :) thanks!